# Quad Tree -- multi level segment trees

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

I recently came across a new data structure called segment trees and then read that it could be extended to two dimensions also but i could not find a good source to read about the details of its implementation and other stuff.
I would like to learn about it from the point of view of using it in a programming contest and not in the field of graphics.Some problems which could be solved using it would also be useful.
Could someone please point me to a good source to read about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extending segment trees to multiple dimensions, especially in a programming contest can turn out to be very difficult and time consuming.

If you need multiple dimensions, you should first learn about Binary Indexed Trees and then try to extend them to multiple dimensions.

Binary Indexed Trees are a data-structure that, in some cases, performs better than Segment Trees, while in others it is simply unsuitable.

The extension to multiple dimensions is trivial when using Segment Trees.

Here you can find [an article about them](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees).

Here you can find [a problem that can help you test your implementation](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?num=1470).

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article about 1D segment trees and their 2D generalization with code samples. But it's in russian, so you would probably have to regard only code samples =)

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're going to find any more sources regarding that. I think that it's left to to the people to understand how k-dimensional segment trees work. In your position I would try to solve a problem which can be done with it. Simple example (and I'm aware that this query can be done in O(1) with some preprocess): rectangular range sum. That is: given a matrix filled with numbers, answer queries which ask for the sum of a sub-matrix. 
Here you can use one semgent tree for splitting up the height and then on each node you make an additional segment tree for the width-based sum.
If you can do that, then you know everything there is to know about 2-dim. segment trees. 
A next challenge would be to allow updating a single element - this gets fast harder, since you have to use some "art" to propagate the changes properly (think of some type of caching inside the segment tree). :)